# Java Null Pointer exception error on android app

Tags: java, android

--- And you guys are way smarter than me!!!

I am having trouble addressing this error.
My app is crashing due to a a null pointer exception.

Here is the error:

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
            at net.miraath.anbiyaa.SimpleMusicStream.updateAudioInfo(SimpleMusicStream.java:524)
            at net.miraath.anbiyaa.SimpleMusicStream.access$1400(SimpleMusicStream.java:30)
            at net.miraath.anbiyaa.SimpleMusicStream$AudioInfoLoadTask.onPostExecute(SimpleMusicStream.java:651)
            at net.miraath.anbiyaa.SimpleMusicStream$AudioInfoLoadTask.onPostExecute(SimpleMusicStream.java:596)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 12:36:30.275    1560-1560/net.miraath.anbiyaa E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-25 12:36:30.275    1560-1560/net.miraath.anbiyaa D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-25 12:36:30.275    1560-1560/net.miraath.anbiyaa W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ed3288)
10-25 12:36:30.275    1560-1560/net.miraath.anbiyaa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service net.miraath.anbiyaa.PlayerService@b3962930 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at net.miraath.anbiyaa.PlayerService.onStart(PlayerService.java:117)
            at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Gere is where I am pulling my hair out: this same code works on the other radios and doesn't crash!!!

Any ideas???

Here is code:

```
  audioTitle.setText(infos[0]);
  listenerNomber.setText("" + getResources().getString(R.string.lable_listiner_nomber)+": " + infos[0]);
  audioTotalTime.setText(infos[5] + "k");
  if(!infos[6].equals(stationOldAudioTitle)){
      ((MiraathRadio)getApplication()).intNotification(stationTitle.getText(), stationTitle.getText(), infos[6], stationIndex);
      stationOldAudioTitle = infos[6];
  }
```

Here is code from playerserver.class file:

```
stationURL = intent.getStringExtra("stationURL");
stationName = intent.getStringExtra("stationName");
stationIndex = intent.getIntExtra("stationIndex",0);
CharSequence stationAudioTitle = intent.getStringExtra("stationAudioTitle");
```

Update: I forgot to mention one key behaving in all this: when I do not press OK on the system dialog box that pops up as a result of the exception,  the app continues to work in the background.  It only when I click OK that the app crashes and the app closes.

Comment: Can you post line 117 from playerservice class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where `infos` is initialized, but based on the exception (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6`), it has a length of 6, and therefore `infos[6]` is out of the array bounds.

Comment: Indeed - many new to Java forget that arrays are indexed from 0, esepcially as there are high level languages where they index from 1.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: I do know that in Java arrays are indexed from zero. I inherited this code from a previous developer wgo was released from this project. I am fixing his errors.

Comment: still looking ... if i increase the index, it fails on the other radio channels. Since the content is populated from an XML file on a remote server, I am wondering if this is the source of my issues (and I do not control the server)???